# MVC 4, Controllers in Area not found by DI container (Windsor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have decided to give areas a try. Using MVC 4, I have setup an area called Admin. I am using Windsor as my DI container and my installer looks like this.

```
container.Register(
            AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().Configure(
                component =>
                    {
                        component.Named(component.Implementation.Name);
                        component.LifestyleTransient();
                    }).WithServiceBase());
```

I have tried several itterations of code in the installer and get the same result. In the watch window I see all the controllers for the main application but not for the area, which is in the same assembly but a different namespace. I would think FromThisAssembly would do the trick but NO!..

Comment: Where is the code for your controller factory?

Comment: Could be a routing issue as well.